# PhpmyAdmin graphical insertion doubles foreign key values

Tags: phpmyadmin

1. I have 3 tables. Very simple stuff. customer, product, order.
2. order table has 2 foreign keys from customer and product.
3. customer table has 1 row(data) and product table has 5 rows.
4. I want to make some dummy orders in order table using phpmyadmin.
5. when I pull down the combo for product, instead of seeing 5 items, I see 10 items. and that's true for customer combo as well.

[image]

[image]

> Please Open the images in new window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the intended behaviour of phpmyadmin. The dropdown lists the possible values twice - first with another field first and the foreign key second, then vice versa. It should make searching for the corresponding value easier.